# poptorootviewcontroller and call the method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to get back from second view controller after press button and call the method in rootViewController. The sample code in obj-c works good, but not in swift (maybe I don't know to write it correctly)
here is the sample code from second view controller.

```
ViewController *presentingViewController = (ViewController *)self.presentingViewController;

    UIButton *button = sender;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{
        [presentingViewController didPressBuyPackageButton:button];
    }];
```

Method called "dismissViewController" doesn't work in my new swift App. It's navigation based App.

Any help please ? 
EDIT:

I have this code in swift in secondViewController:

```
var button : UIButton = sender as UIButton
        var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: {
            vc.buyPackageButton(button)
        })
```

But now, when I get back to the rootviewcontroller (viewcontroller) I have an error at the alertcontroller
at line:

```
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.